# mysql how do I hide lines with specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I hide lines with value 0 of 'rechamadas'.
I've tried with 'where' and the result is the same with or without it.
'case when' returns almost the same but with nulls instead of 0s.
I need something like this:

```
Data     NumeroCliente       Rechamadas
15/07/21 16481218527         2
17/07/21 16910110913         2
17/07/21 16030926362         1
```

---

```
select
date_format(datahora, '%d/%m/%y') as 'Data',
numerocliente as NumeroCliente,
count(numerocliente) - 1 as Rechamadas 
from ligacoes
-- where numerocliente > 1
group by numerocliente
order by datahora
```

```
Data     NumeroCliente       Rechamadas
15/07/21 16481218527         0
17/07/21 16910110913         2
17/07/21 16030926362         0
17/07/21 16200904978         0
21/07/21 16030219377         0
21/07/21 16900314989         2
21/07/21 16090625771         0
22/07/21 16790310530         1
22/07/21 16080429611         0
```

edit1: My goal is to know how many times each 'NumeroCliente' reappears per date. I've manage to done that with 'count(numerocliente) - 1' cuz the first time it appears doesnt count to what I need. The table 'ligacoes' has tree columns which are 'numerocliente' (an id to each customer), 'datahora' (datetime format) and 'codigooperador' (fk).

thank you for your time!

Comment: If this is MySQL then why have you tagged SQL Server? MySQL <> SQL Server!

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense so removing those rows is the least of your worries. I would make a separate question with sample data and your expected result. What you have apparently done is provided a current result and expected result. But we have no idea what data you're working with or what you're trying to do.

Comment: this is my first post and Im pretty new to programming at all. pls have some patience. Im looking to delete the tag but dont know how

Comment: @IgorHIT welcome to SO. You can edit your own question after asking and you are encouraged to do so to either alter tags or provide further information requested in these kinds of comments.

Comment: thank you @danblack! already done some changes to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL (and many other SQL implementations) have a `HAVING` clause which is an result limitation that is applied after the `GROUP BY`:

So your query becomes:

```
select
date_format(datahora, '%d/%m/%y') as 'Data',
numerocliente as NumeroCliente,
count(numerocliente) - 1 as Rechamadas 
from ligacoes
where numerocliente > 1
group by numerocliente
HAVING Rechamadas > 0
order by datahora
```

ref: [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having 'Rechamadas' > 0' at line 8

Comment: after [checking manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html), HAVING comes before ORDER BY. Thank you error messages.

Comment: thank you for time and patience! I finally have the output I want. thank you!

Comment: `HAVING` is standard SQL and should be supported in *all* [SQL] databases.